# Changing browser name in qt5.8 webengine

Tags: c++, qt, http-headers, user-agent

I want to name my webbrowser made in qt5.8 to some custom name like "My WebBrowser" using http user agent.My current user agent is `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.8.0 Chrome/53.0.2785.148 Safari/537.36`. How should I change it so that my browser name is identified as "My WebBrowser" instead of Qt5.8.0 or Chrome53.

```
    class WebView:public QObject{
        void acceptFullScreen(QWebEngineFullScreenRequest request){
            request.accept();
        }

    public:
        char* home_page;
        QWebEngineView* view=new QWebEngineView();
        WebView(char* page=(char*)"https://google.com"){
            this->home_page=page;
            createWebView();
            this->view->settings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::FullScreenSupportEnabled,true);
            connect(this->view->page(),&QWebEnginePage::fullScreenRequested,this,&WebView::acceptFullScreen);
            this->view->page()->profile()->setHttpUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.8.0 MyBrowser/1.0 Chrome/53.0.2785.148 Safari/537.36");
        }
        void createWebView(){
            this->view->load(QUrl(this->home_page));
        }
        QWebEngineView* returnView(){
            return this->view;
        }
        void home(){
            this->view->load(QUrl(this->home_page));
        }
        void spinnerStarted(){
            QWidget* widget=(QWidget*)this->view->parent();
            QTabWidget* tabwidget=(QTabWidget*)widget->parent();
            std::cout<<tabwidget<<std::endl;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [QWebEngineProfile::setHttpUserAgent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineprofile.html#setHttpUserAgent) to set a custom user agent.

Comment: I used that but still the name appears to `Qt5.8.0`

Comment: I guess you have to use `QWebEngineProfile::defaultProfile()->setHttpUserAgent("my web browser");`, nut sure if you can get the `QWebEngineProfile` from somewhere else.

Comment: and it does not work if your set the user agent of the page like that? I hope you actually set the user agent to something else and not like your code shows the same value it has by default :D

Comment: if I just write "my browser" then its detected as "unknown" and i found th user agent of qupzilla as "mozilla/5.0 (x11; linux x86_64) applewebkit/538.1 (khtml, like gecko) qupzilla/1.8.9 safari/538.1" I just want to rename my QtWebEngineView to some custom name

Comment: well what is displayed as the user agent depends on the way you read the data (I guess you let some website do the job and those might not detect your custom text as a known browser obviously, if you look at the user agent of other browsers they usually send a lot of unrelated other browser engines too), but in general can you use whatever you want. Btw I noticed you set the user agent after you start loading the page, that is maybe not so good, set every settings before you call `load` or your custom functions `createWebView` etc. That might fix some weird problems.